# Как создать цикл, который вычитает число до определенного значения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Как создать цикл, который будет вычитать из 20 число 5 до тех пор, пока значение 20 не станет равным -5?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://google.gik-team.com/?q=%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8B+%D0%B2+python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num = 20

while True:
    print(f'{num}-{5}={num - 5}')  # как работает внутри
    num -= 5
    if num == -5:
         break

print(num) # -5
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: условие можно задать сразу  `while num!=-5`  , тогда  `if`  из тела цикла можно убрать